# Winston Logger not working outside playwright test listeners/reporters

Tags: typescript, logging, automation, winston, playwright

Background: I have implemented automation framework with POM Design pattern and playwright using typescript language.

I have implemented winston logger to create my custom logger for automation framework.
Below is the code snippet for logger

```ts
const logger = winston.createLogger({
    exitOnError:false,
    silent:false,
    levels : Levels,
        transports: [
            new winston.transports.File({
                filename: 'debug'+'.log',     
                format: combine(
                    format.colorize(),
                    splat(),
                    timestamp(),
                    customFormat
              )        
            }),
            new winston.transports.Console({
                format: combine(
                    format.colorize(),
                    splat(),
                    timestamp(),
                    customFormat
                )}
            ),
        ]
    });
```

I have implemented Test Listeners as well and leveraged above logger to log info/error in console and file during test run.

```js
    onBegin(config, suite) {
        logger.info(`Starting the run with ${suite.allTests().length} tests`);
      }
```

But the logger is only working for Test Listener.

If I use `logger.info()` or `console.log()` in Page class or Test function - it doesn't log anything in console or file. Any suggestions as how to fix it ?

Comment: I personnally don't know automation, but for the the case of your Page class or Test function, are sure the logger is instanciated (maybe plant a breakpoint on the create line) ?

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. Helped to identify the problem

Answer (score 1):

Problem identified: the logger was not getting instantiated in the page class.

Fixed the issue as below:

1. exported logger to default by adding the following code at the end of the logger definition file:

   `export default logger;`
2. Imported and used the logger in the page.